# How to run create-react-app on linux terminal

Tags: linux, reactjs, create-react-app

I have installed nodejs and yarn on my computer (Linux Deepin).
I have also installed create-react-app globally. However, the create-react-app command is not running. I keep getting the error: bash: create-react-app: command not found.

Is there some configuration I am missing? Because I have seen the create-react-app that was installed globally.

NodeJS - v6.3.1
Yarn - 1.6.0
OS version Linux Deepin -15

Comment: If it is installed globaly then it should work.Please share the command used to install it globally

Comment: yarn global add create-react-app

Answer (score 2):

Add yarn global path to your path variable
the following appends yarn global path to your  ~/.bashrc

```
 echo  'export PATH="$PATH:$(yarn global bin)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

if you are using other shell like zsh make sure you append to the correct file for zsh use

```
 echo  'export PATH="$PATH:$(yarn global bin)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

**finally make sure you restart your terminal.**

Comment: running the command above and runing create-react-app i got this error: /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the command is already in your path?? If you just installed it, maybe, just close and relaunch terminal ;)

Comment: I dont know. I am new to linux. Trying to find that out on google. Can you show me?

Comment: you could check @Mehari answer, it is pretty much what I was about to explain :D